# How to publish message from AWS Lambda to Raspberry Pi using MQTT in Python?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, mqtt, aws-iot-core

I'd like to send messages from AWS Lambda to Raspberry Pi using MQTT in Python. I'm looking for some reference code.

Some of the examples I found uses AWS IoT endpoint to communicate, IIUC wouldn't that be to communicate from Raspberry Pi to AWS IoT? What info do we need in order to connect to Raspberry Pi? Do we need certificates info in the AWS Lambda? How to get the  Raspberry Pi's web address/endpoint that I can use in AWS Lambda?

I appreciate any help, thank you!

I'm new to AWS IoT core/Raspberry pi. I installed certificates in Raspberry Pi. I have looked up for code to communicate to Raspberry pi from AWS Lambda, but couldn't find any references.

Comment: So your Lambda function needs to publish to an MQTT broker. That broker could be `AWS IoT` (see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/use-aws-iot-core-mqtt-broker-with-standard-mqtt-libraries/) for some examples) or any other accessible broker (you could host this on the pi, if you have a fixed IP etc, but a hosted service, such as [hive](https://www.hivemq.com/), is probably simpler). The Pi needs to connect to the same broker and subscribe to the relevant topic.

Comment: Thank you Brits! Looks like we always communicate with the IoT core endpoint whether we are publishing from the rasp pi or from the lambda function.